# what happens to existing data when we change model Charfield to IntegerField in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

When the following migration is applied,

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('outlets', '0009_auto_20190920_1155'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='outlet',
            name='country',
            field=models.IntegerField(choices=[(1, 'UAE'), (2, 'India')],
                                      verbose_name='Country'),
        ),
    ]
```

The following error happens,

```
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "United States"
```

This is because i am changing CharField to IntegerField and following data "United States" already exists in db, Also i read in similar question, django migrations is not able to handle such changes.

Is there any way to do this operation, without deleting existing data ?

Comment: You can do it manually in django shell, just take all entries of country field and where 'United States' put 1 and where "India" put 2 problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to things go smoothly, you need to integrate data mutation within a migration

As sample:

```py
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion

def migrate_country(apps, schema_editor):
    Outlet = apps.get_model('your_app_name', 'Outlet')
    # You can either do
    Outlet.objects.all().update(
        temp_country= 'what_ever_update you want'
    )
    # Or
    for outlet in Outlet.objects.all():
        outlet.temp_country='your_transformation_result'
        outlet.save() # Please note django will use it's save method. 
                      # Your eventual override will just be ignore

def reverse_country(apps, schema_editor):
    """
    Do want you want when rolling back your migration
    """
    ....

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ...
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='Outlet',
            name='temp_outlet',
            name='country',
            field=models.IntegerField(choices=[(1, 'UAE'), (2, 'India')],
                                      verbose_name='Country'),
        ),
        # Now, you have temp_outlet available on your schema!
        migrations.RunPython(migrate_country, reverse_country),
        # We dump "old" field
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='article',
            name='outlet',
        ),
        # We rename the 'temp' field as excpected!
        migrations.RenameField(
        model_name='Outlet',
            old_name='oldname',
            new_name='newname',
    ),
    ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to do this in three separate migrations.

First, add the IntegerField, either as null=True or a default of 0.

Secondly, add a data migration that takes the value in the existing CharField, looks up the matching integer value, and sets it to the new IntegerField.

Thirdly, delete the CharField, rename the IntegerField and remove the default/null.